# Unable to load even Test ad in react native using react-native-google-mobile-ads

Tags: javascript, react-native, admob

I tried loading banner ad. it just showing the gray box

```
import {BannerAd, BannerAdSize, TestIds} from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const adUnitId = DEV ? TestIds.BANNER : 'ca-app-pub-6931860583577865/2388071525'; function HomeScreen({navigation}) { return ( <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
return (
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <Text>{TestIds.BANNER}</Text>
  <BannerAd
    unitId={TestIds.BANNER}
    size={BannerAdSize.ANCHORED_ADAPTIVE_BANNER}
    onAdOpened={e => {
      console.log('onAdOpened');
      console.log(e);
    }}
    onAdFailedToLoad={e => {
      console.log('onAdFailedToLoad');`
      console.log(e);
    }}
    onAdLoaded={e => {
      console.log('onAdLoaded');
      console.log(e);
    }}
    onAdClosed={e => {
      console.log('onAdClosed');
      console.log(e);
    }}
  />
</SafeAreaView>
); }
```

Error:[Error: [googleMobileAds/error-code-no-fill] The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.]

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have followed the installation steps for
   `react-native-google-mobile-ads` correctly. You can refer to the
   documentation here:
   https://github.com/react-native-admob/react-native-admob#installation.
2. Make sure you have a valid test device set up. You can set this up
   by following the instructions here:
   https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices

To display a test ad using `react-native-google-mobile-ads` in React Native:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { AdMobBanner } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const AdBanner = () => {
  const [adUnitID, setAdUnitID] = useState('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'); // Replace with your own ad unit ID
  const [adLoaded, setAdLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAdLoaded(false);
  }, [adUnitID]);

  const onAdFailedToLoad = (error) => {
    console.log('Ad failed to load: ', error);
  }

  const onAdLoaded = () => {
    setAdLoaded(true);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {adLoaded ? (
        <AdMobBanner
          adSize="banner"
          adUnitID={adUnitID}
          onAdFailedToLoad={onAdFailedToLoad}
          onAdLoaded={onAdLoaded}
          testDevices={[AdMobBanner.simulatorId]}
          servePersonalizedAds={false}
        />
      ) : (
        <Text>Loading ad...</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

export default AdBanner;
```

**Note** In this example, a test ad unit ID (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111) and the simulator ID as the test device. You will need to replace these with your own ad unit ID and test devices when testing on real devices.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-admob/react-native-admob#installation.     the link is not working. <AdMobBanner/> component in not present in documentation of react-native-google-mobile-ads i am bit confuse how you are using it

Comment: https://aboutreact.com/react-native-admob-ads/
this is best example and working. Please check it